# checking the status of a process and starting another script hwen it finishes in unix

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I'm writing a script in which it'll check the current status of a running job and as soon as it finishes it'll start another script within a shell script. Need to get some idea on that.

```
#!/bin/ksh

#checking the current status of the job:
ps -ef |grep /spaet1b/work/scripts/loading.ksh
if [$? -eq 0 ];
then
cd /home/ashish/
./trigger_su.ksh
exit 0
fi
```

Please correct me.

Comment: ksh is not bash.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `pgrep -f`

```
pgrep -f loading.ksh
if [$? -eq 0 ];
then
cd /home/ashish/
./trigger_su.ksh
exit 0
fi
```